# Does 'samadhi-nimitta' mean 'undistractable-lucidity-themes'?

Tags: pali, nimitta

I read the following on the internet:

> In MN 44, the four remembrance-establishings (are)
> undistractable-lucidity-themes.
>
> Any topic for satipatthana "mindfulness", can be a topic for samādhi
> nimitta, or a subject for jhāna meditation to investigate with
> dhamma-vicaya, vitakka and vicāra, upekkha, sati and sampajāno in the
> higher jhānas. The nimitta of samādhi can be visual, or conceptual,
> and both, just as it can be in guarding the sense doors.

> In AN 4.14, samādhi nimitta suggested one develops are the corpse in
> various stages.
>
> Idha, bhikkhave, bhikkhu uppannaṃ bhaddakaṃ samādhinimittaṃ
> anurakkhati aṭṭhikasaññaṃ puḷavakasaññaṃ vinīlakasaññaṃ
> vicchiddakasaññaṃ uddhumātakasaññaṃ. It’s when a monk preserves a
> meditation subject that’s a fine basis of undistractible-lucidity: the
> perception of a skeleton, a worm-infested corpse, a livid corpse, a
> split open corpse, or a bloated corpse.

Does the term 'samādhi nimitta' in MN 44 above really mean '*undistractable-lucidity-themes*'? If so, why is 'samādhi nimitta' translated as '*basis of undistractible-lucidity*' in AN 4.14 above?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it really meansthe theme/sign  of Samadhi.
The question is Why Satipatthana are sign of Samadhi?
Its because when  you are mindful of one or all Satipatthana. You are grounded forever in them.

> ‘Atthi kāyo’ti vā panassa sati paccupaṭṭhitā hoti yāvadeva ñāṇamattāya
> paṭissatimattāya anissito ca viharati, na ca kiñci loke upādiyati.

What is Smadhi ?
Its tranquilizing all Sankahara. you tranquilise them by way of Sila, Samvar, Sampajankari.

And all this is possible only because your rememberful-ness is established. Only in the presence of Sati all these Akushala Dhamma do not arise.  and if arise do not proliferate.

And thats why , Sati is Sign of Samadhi.
You are in samadhi , when you are just in Sati. with no Akushala dhamma.

An 4.14 is nothing but Mindfulness of Body.

Answer (score -1):

About the word '[nimitta](https://suttacentral.net/define/nimitta?lang=en)', the various Pali dictionaries offer multiple meanings:

> nimitta
>
> masculine, neuter
>
> 1. a sign or mark by which something or someone is recognized or identified or known or defined; a distinguishing mark or appearance; a
>    perceived (enduring) attribute, predicate (especially that of
>    permanence); an attribution
> 2. the organ of generation (of either sex), the pudenda
> 3. an object or appearance or happening which is significant, which expresses more than itself; a sign, a significant appearance; an omen,
>    a portent
> 4. an indication, a hint
> 5. what one notes or marks; an object of thought or meditation or concentration; an image
> 6. an internal/ appearance or total awareness; a mental impression (appearing as an early stage of jhāna, a sign of progress)
> 7. a ground, a cause, a reason
>
> New Concise Pali English Dictionary

Many suttas (such as SN 45.8, MN 117, MN 27 & AN 10.61) describe the place of mindfulness (sati) & situational awareness (sampajānna) in the Noble Eightfold Path, where mindfulness & sampajano are established prior to jhana.

MN 117 says:

> *In one of right mindfulness, right concentration comes into being*.

MN 27 says:

> *When they have this entire spectrum of noble ethics, this noble
> contentment, this noble sense restraint, and this **noble mindfulness
> and situational awareness**, they frequent a secluded lodging—a
> wilderness, the root of a tree, a hill, a ravine, a mountain cave, a
> charnel ground, a forest, the open air, a heap of straw... Giving up
> covetousness for the world, they meditate with a heart rid of
> covetousness, cleansing the mind of covetousness...They give up these
> five hindrances, corruptions of the heart that weaken wisdom.... Then,
> quite secluded from sensual pleasures, secluded from unskillful
> qualities, **they enter and remain in the first absorption**...*

AN 10.61 says:

> *Thus associating with good persons, becoming full, fills up hearing the good Dhamma. Hearing the good Dhamma, becoming full, fills up faith. Faith, becoming full, fills up careful attention. Careful attention, becoming full, fills up **mindfulness and clear comprehension.** Mindfulness and clear comprehension, becoming full, fill up restraint of the sense faculties. Restraint of the sense faculties, becoming full, fills up the three kinds of good conduct. The three kinds of good conduct, becoming full, fill up the **four establishments of mindfulness**. The four establishments of mindfulness, becoming full, fill up the seven factors of enlightenment. The **seven factors of enlightenment [which include samadhi & jhana]**, becoming full, fill up true knowledge and liberation. Thus there is nutriment for true knowledge and liberation, and in this way they become full.*

About the terms 'samādhinimittā' & 'samādhiparikkhārā', MN 44 says:

> *“But ma’am, what is immersion (samādhi)? What things are the nimittā of
> immersion? What things are the parikkhārā for immersion? What is the
> development of immersion?”*
>
> *“Unification of the mind is immersion.*
>
> *The four kinds of mindfulness meditation are the nimittā of immersion.*
>
> *The four right efforts are the parikkhārā for immersion.*
>
> *The cultivation, development, and making much of these very same
> things is the development (bhāvanā) of immersion.”*

There is nothing in MN 44 to indicate the place of satipatthana (mindfulness meditation) diverges from its natural place in the Noble Eightfold Path, which, per MN 117 says: "*in one of right effort, right mindfulness comes into being; in one of right mindfulness, right concentration comes into being*". Therefore, the term 'samādhinimittā' does not appear to mean 'theme/sign of samadhi', thus to imply the 'samādhinimittā' is a product/fruit/result of samadhi. Instead, per the 7th meaning in the dictionary, the term 'samādhinimittā' appears to mean '*a ground, a cause, a reason for/of samadhi*'. Thus MN 44 refers to how 'samādhinimittā' & 'samādhiparikkhārā' are used in the development of samadhi.